# Can we assign a unsigned int varaible, 0xFULL literal

Tags: c++, c

I wanted to understand the difference between the following two definitions

```
unsigned long long id = 0x0FULL; //should be correct
unsigned int store = 0X0FULL;  // ?? Can this be done 

printf("id is : 0x%llx store is : 0x%x\n",id,store);
```

An output for the the two variables returns the same value

```
id is : 0xf store is : 0xf
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a coincidence that it happens to spell out a word. The `ULL` suffix means you've got an `unsigned long long` literal, and `0xF` or `0x0F` you already know: that's 15, except expressed in hexadecimal.

Comment: You mean 15 in decimal right?
Also I get that 0xFULL is a `ULL` literal so you mean would it be wrong to do something like 
`unsigned int store = 0X0FULL;`

Comment: @cmidi I mean that's decimal 15, expressed in hexadecimal. I see I worded it a bit confusingly. `unsigned int store = 0x0FULL;` is valid but weird. It's valid because there is an implicit conversion between any two integral types, including from `unsigned long long` to `unsigned int`. It's weird because if you want an `unsigned int`, why would you use an `ULL` suffix?

Comment: I was just trying to chase down a problem in a open source library code, which has something similar in the code

Answer (score 5):

`0x0f` is an `int` with the value 15.

`0x0full` is an `unsigned long long` with the value 15.